# SAVE AS does not work from js imacros error. RuntimeError: Wrong path 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\iMacros\ok\', line 4 (Error code: -932)

Tags: javascript, imacros

SAVE AS does not work from js 
.iim only work Why is not it working save from js? why? help! p.s sorry for bad english!
error:
RuntimeError: Wrong path 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\iMacros\ok\', line 4 (Error code: -932)

```html
this is .js file
var goto_date;
    goto_date =  "CODE:";
 goto_date +=  "SET !DATASOURCE urldata.txt" + "\n";
 goto_date +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
 goto_date +=  "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";        
    goto_date +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\iMacros\ok\ FILE=temp.txt" + "\n";
 iimPlay(goto_date);

this is .iim file
SET !DATASOURCE urldata.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}       
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\iMacros\ok\ FILE=temp.txt
```

Comment: try replacing all "\" with "\\"

Comment: I tried
But it does not work
why?

Comment: C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\iMacros\\ok\\
 not work :(

Comment: thank you!
I solved!
it works!